# How to see insert statements in SQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Is there a way for me to see the insert statements that were used in a SQL table I created. I have provided a picture of the table. I just want to see the statements used to insert these values.

[image]

Comment: What application are you using? In Aqua Data Studio you can highlight the columns, right click create insert statements

Comment: I am using phpMyAdmin

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you want. Do you want "ALL THE HISTORY" of how the table was modified, or you just want a list of inserts that will re-create your data?

Comment: Do you want to see the exact statements used (like if they were inserted and then updated you want to see both sql statements) or do you just want to generate the insert statements?

Comment: Either or would work, I just need to recycle the insert statements for a few tables I have and would like to do it with ease.

Comment: http://www.endycahyono.com/article/generating-insert-statements-from-mysql-to-be-run-on-sql-server

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9306/how-do-you-mysqldump-specific-tables

Comment: You should be able to do export as full insert statements, it will give you the statements which built the table.

Comment: Use `mysqldump "databasename" > dbdump.sql`. This `dbdump.sql` file will contain all the create and insert statements

Comment: @Arihant and I run this statement in myPhPAdmin?

Comment: Click on the Export link and select the format then you can get a SQL script. FYR, https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin-export-table

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Arihant answer, 
go to 
xampp folder 
open cmd there
then

```
cd mysql
cd bin
```

then run command given by @Arihant

```
mysqldump <databasename> <tablename> > dbdump.sql
```

in same path xampp/mysql/bin you will find a file of name dbdump.sql having all create and insert statements

Comment: It's unlikely he has write permission to the `mysql/bin` directory. He should write to a file in his home directory.